# Check for multiple distinct occurrences by group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Input Data

```
   Some_Table
   ST_Field1   ST_Field2
   Apple       A
   Apple       A
   Apple       D
   Orange      D
   Orange      E
   Orange      Z
   Pear        D
   Pear        G 
   Pear        C

   Reference_Table
   RT_Field1   RT_Field2
   1           A
   1           B
   1           C
   2           D
   2           E
   2           F
   3           G
```

Expected Result:

```
   ST_Field1   ST_Field2
   Orange      D
   Orange      E

CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE
  ( ST_Field1 VARCHAR(100),
    ST_Field2 VARCHAR(100)
  );

INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Apple','A');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Apple','A');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Apple','D');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Orange','D');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Orange','E');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Orange','Z');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Pear','D');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Pear','G');
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES ('Pear','C');

CREATE TABLE REFERENCE_TABLE
  ( RT_Field1 INTEGER,
    RT_Field2 VARCHAR(100)
  );

INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (1,'A');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (1,'B');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (1,'C');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (2,'D');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (2,'E');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (2,'F');
INSERT INTO REFERENCE_TABLE VALUES (3,'G');
```

It can be assumed that RT_Field2 is unique.

I'm looking to get the records from Some_Table which have multiple distinct values from RT_Field2, group by RT_Field1, by ST_Field1.

So from the reference table {A,B,C} are a grouping. I want to see if for a given ST_Field1 I see either {A,B};{B,c},{A,C}. I don't, I see A and C present, but across Apple and Pear.

The only success is Orange, where I'm looking for {D,E},{D,F}, or {E,F} and find D and E both for Orange.

I have:

```
WITH DUP_VALUES_RTF2 AS
  ( SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT DST.ST_Field1,
                   DST.ST_Field2,
                   COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY RT.RT_Field1) cnt_RTF1
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                           ST_Field1,
                           ST_Field2
                      FROM Some_Table
                   ) DST
             INNER
              JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE RT
                ON DST.ST_Field2 = RT.RT_Field2
           ) TMP
     WHERE cnt_RTF1 > 1
  )
SELECT * 
  FROM SOME_TABLE ST
 WHERE EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM DUP_VALUES_RTF2 DVR
            WHERE ST.ST_Field1 = DVR.ST_Field1
              AND ST.ST_Field2 = DVR.ST_Field2
         );
```

Which doesn't even really come close because it doesn't handle the grouping at all correctly and is really ugly. Maybe I'm just going brain dead after 5pm.

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for that, it was a good read. I didn't realize how big of a blind spot these types of questions were for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to match on `st_field1` and `rt_field1`, looking for duplicates in `rt_field2`.  You can use window functions for this:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, rt.rt_field1, rt.rt_field2,
             min(rt.rt_field2) over (partition by s.st_field1, r.rt_field1) as min_rt2,
             max(rt.rt_field2) over (partition by s.st_field1, r.rt_field1) as max_rt2             
      from sometable s join
           reference_table r
           on s.st_field2 = r.rt_field2
     ) s
where min_rt2 <> max_rt2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below

```
; with distinctSet as 
(select distinct s.*,RT_Field1 from SOME_TABLE s join REFERENCE_TABLE r on s.ST_Field2=r.RT_Field2
)
, 
uniqueSet as 
(
select RT_Field1,ST_Field1 
from distinctSet
group by RT_Field1,ST_Field1
having count(1)>1
),
resultSet as 
(
select
distinct 
s.*
from SOME_TABLE s 
join REFERENCE_TABLE r 
on s.ST_Field2=r.RT_Field2
join uniqueSet u
on u.RT_Field1=r.RT_Field1
and u.ST_Field1=s.ST_Field1
)
select * from resultSet
```

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! Accepted the other answer just because the window function makes it clean, but this one is good in that in just relies on vanilla sql